# Creating linked-list in python without using native lists

Tags: python, linked-list, python-unittest

I'm trying to implement a dynamic singly linked-list in python without native lists. The results of the unit tests for the batch of code is unfortunately coming up with failures. Pycharm hasn't flagged any syntactical errors and I'm at a loss for what parts of my code would be wrong.

```
import unittest

class linked_list:

    front = rear = None
    current = None #used in iterator

    class node:

        def __init__(self, value, next):
            self.value = value
            self.next = next

    def empty(self):
        return self.empty

    def push_front(self, value):
        x = self.node(value, self.front)
        self.front = x
        if not self.rear:
            self.rear = x
        return x

    def push_back(self, value):
        if self.empty():
            self.front = self.rear = self.node(value, None)
        else:
            x = self.node(value, None)
            self.rear.next = x
            self.rear = x
        x = self.node(value, self.rear)
        self.rear = x
        return x

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise RuntimeError("Empty List")
        x = self.front.value
        self.front = self.front.next
        if not self.front:
            self.rear = None
        return x

    def pop_back(self, value, next):
        if self.empty():
            raise RuntimeError("Empty List")
        y = self.rear.value
        x = self.front
        while x.next != self.rear:
            x = x.next
        self.rear = x
        return y
```

The linked list unit tests:

```
class test_linked_list (unittest.TestCase):
    def test_none(self):
        self.assertTrue(linked_list().empty())
    def test_pop_front_empty(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, lambda: linked_list().pop_front())
    def test_pop_back_empty(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, lambda: linked_list().pop_back())
    def test_push_back_pop_front(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_back(1)
        ll.push_back(2)
        ll.push_back(3)
        self.assertFalse(ll.empty())
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 1)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 2)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 3)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
    def test_push_front_pop_front(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_front(1)
        ll.push_front(2)
        ll.push_front(3)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 3)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 2)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 1)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
    def test_push_front_pop_back(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_front(1)
        ll.push_front(2)
        ll.push_front(3)
        self.assertFalse(ll.empty())
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 1)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 2)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 3)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
    def test_push_back_pop_back(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_back(1)
        ll.push_back("foo")
        ll.push_back([3,2,1])
        self.assertFalse(ll.empty())
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(),[3,2,1])
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), "foo")
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 1)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
```

Edit:

Below are the Errors/Failures from the debugger:

> Failure Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "G:\CS2_Assignment1\Assignment 1.py", line 101, in
>   test_push_back_pop_back
>       self.assertFalse(ll.empty()) AssertionError: > is not false
>
> Failure Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "G:\CS2_Assignment1\Assignment 1.py", line 72, in
>   test_push_back_pop_front
>       self.assertFalse(ll.empty()) AssertionError: > is not false
>
> Failure Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "G:\CS2_Assignment1\Assignment 1.py", line 91, in
>   test_push_front_pop_back
>       self.assertFalse(ll.empty()) AssertionError: > is not false

Comment: You could start by showing what the specific failures are.

Comment: I don't know about other errors but the `empty` method returns its own function object `return self.empty` so you don't detect empty properly.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited to include errors.

Comment: `push_back` creates two nodes... the second i think shouldn't be there.

Comment: you never really define the value of `self.empty`

Comment: You need to go through the errors one by one and knock them down. `TypeError: pop_back() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'value' and 'next'` is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test-first methodology like this is a great way to write good code. `unittest` tells you where the errors are. If you can't fix them by visual inspection, then you can construct temporary example scripts that you use to step through the code in a debugger or sprinkle with prints to see what's going on.

I used `unittest.main()` to run and got several errors. One was: `TypeError: pop_back() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'value' and 'next'` And sure enough, the method had too many parameters `def pop_back(self, value, next):`. So I just removed them.

After going through the remaining ones, a script that passes unit tests is:

```
import unittest

class linked_list:

    front = rear = None
    current = None #used in iterator

    class node:

        __slots__ = ['value', 'next']

        def __init__(self, value, next):
            self.value = value
            self.next = next

    def empty(self):
        return not self.front

    def push_front(self, value):
        x = self.node(value, self.front)
        self.front = x
        if not self.rear:
            self.rear = x

    def push_back(self, value):
        if self.empty():
            self.front = self.rear = self.node(value, None)
        else:
            x = self.node(value, None)
            self.rear.next = x
            self.rear = x

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise RuntimeError("Empty List")
        x = self.front.value
        self.front = self.front.next
        if not self.front:
            self.rear = None
        return x

    def pop_back(self):
        if self.empty():
            raise RuntimeError("Empty List")
        y = self.rear.value
        if not self.front.next:
            self.front = self.rear = None
        else:
            x = self.front
            while x.next is not self.rear:
                x = x.next
            x.next = None
            self.rear = x
        return y


class test_linked_list (unittest.TestCase):
    def test_none(self):
        self.assertTrue(linked_list().empty())
    def test_pop_front_empty(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, lambda: linked_list().pop_front())
    def test_pop_back_empty(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, lambda: linked_list().pop_back())
    def test_push_back_pop_front(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_back(1)
        ll.push_back(2)
        ll.push_back(3)
        self.assertFalse(ll.empty())
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 1)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 2)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 3)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
    def test_push_front_pop_front(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_front(1)
        ll.push_front(2)
        ll.push_front(3)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 3)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 2)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_front(), 1)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
    def test_push_front_pop_back(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_front(1)
        ll.push_front(2)
        ll.push_front(3)
        self.assertFalse(ll.empty())
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 1)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 2)
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 3)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())
    def test_push_back_pop_back(self):
        ll = linked_list()
        ll.push_back(1)
        ll.push_back("foo")
        ll.push_back([3,2,1])
        self.assertFalse(ll.empty())
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(),[3,2,1])
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), "foo")
        self.assertEquals(ll.pop_back(), 1)
        self.assertTrue(ll.empty())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: That really helps a great deal. Can you elaborate on the use of __slots__? Is it forcing a format when constructing the node class?

Comment: I forgot to mention slots. Python objects have a `dict` to hold local variables. With `__slots__ = ["value", "next"]`, `node` objects don't get per-object dicts at the cost of only being able to use those two variable names. For small objects like `node` where many could be created, its a performance enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

Some errors have been pointed out by others; e.g., as @tdelaney says, `self.empty()` returns itself, which is a method and always evaluates to True.

But I think the overall design can also be improved, and perhaps showing a different implementation will be helpful to you (well, I hope so!). So here we go.

First, let's have a separate `Node` class. (It's OK to embed it as you did, but "flat is better than nested".) Also `__repr__` makes debugging easier and is generally a user-friendly thing to do.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next_node):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_node

    def __repr__(self):
        type_name = type(self).__name__
        return '{}({!r}, {!r})'.format(type_name, self.value, self.next)
```

Then the `LinkedList` itself. In addition to the API you defined, it'd be nice to implement the iterator protocol, so we can do `for x in llist`. Also, the list's emptiness (or the lack of it) sounds like an attribute and it's easy to compute, so let's make it accessible like an attribute, by using `property`. And, true to the idea of a singly linked list, I don't keep a reference to the last node.

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self._current = None  # for iteration

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} {}>'.format(type(self).__name__, self.head)

    def __iter__(self):
       self._current = self.head
       return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._current is None:
            raise StopIteration
        current, self._current = self._current, self._current.next
        return current

    @property
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def push_front(self, value):
        self.head = Node(value, self.head)

    def push_back(self, value):
        last_node = self._find_last()
        if last_node is None:
            # list is empty, so push_front is the same as push_back
            self.push_front(value)
        else:
            last_node.next = Node(value, None)

    def pop_front(self):
        if self.is_empty:
            raise RuntimeError('list empty')
        value, self.head = self.head.value, self.head.next
        return value

    def pop_back(self):
        last_node = self._find_last()
        if last_node is None:
            raise RuntimeError('list empty')
        if last_node is self.head:
            self.head = None
        else:
            # at least two nodes left; need to find the penultimate node
            for node in self:
                if node.next is last_node:
                    node.next = None
        return last_node.value

    def _find_last(self):
        # Helper method for finding the last node
        last_node = None
        for node in self:
            last_node = node
        return last_node
```

I doctested this implementation and it passed:

```
>>> llist = LinkedList()
>>> llist.is_empty
True
>>> llist.push_front(1)
>>> llist.is_empty
False
>>> llist.push_front(0)
>>> llist.push_back(2)
>>> llist.push_back(3)
>>> llist
<LinkedList Node(0, Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, None))))>
>>> for node in llist:
...     print(node.value)
0
1
2
3
>>> llist.pop_front()
0
>>> llist
<LinkedList Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, None)))>
>>> llist.pop_back()
3
>>> llist
<LinkedList Node(1, Node(2, None))>
```

Not prefect, though, because I chose a very simple implementation of `_find_last`. It requires `for` loop to yield nodes, not their values as one might expect, and it forces each `pop_back()` call to iterate over the list twice in most case. But I guess it's good enough of a demo for now.

Answer (score -1):

For starters, your `linked_list` class needs an `__init__` method.  Second, you have a method named empty so you shouldn't have a variable with the same name.  So:

```
class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):  
        self.front = self.rear = None
        self.current = None #used in iterator
        self._empty = True

    def empty(self):
        return self._empty
```

Comment: He doesn't need an __init__ because when the object is first created, the `front` and `rear` attributes are handled by the class level attributes by the same name. He could track a separate `_empty` attribute but it would be better to just use one of the existing attributes instead.

Comment: True, as long as you never want to create a second linked list.  No experienced programmer would ever write a linked list class without a constructor.

Comment: No, as soon as you assign the variable `self.front = something` you get a variable in the object namespace that masks the one at the class level. It works fine without an initializer for any number of list instances.